# Jquery Menu that on click toggles class to expand one list level at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, menu, contextmenu

issue#1 So I have a menu that asks for the Make, model and year of a car. I have got the basic functionality working but my code isn't clean. How can I make this DRYer?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {


$('li.menu-item-type-custom').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('ul.sub-menu').toggleClass('expand-menu');
}); 
$('li.menu-item-type-custom').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('> ul.sub-menu').toggleClass('expand-menu');
}); 


});
```

issue#2
I also want only one child of each make or model to be shown at a time. Right now if I click on make 1 and  make 2 then the text overlaps and it looks bad. I tried

```
$('li.menu-item-type-custom').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('> ul.sub-menu').toggleClass('expand-menu');
      if( $(this).hasClass("expand-menu") ) {
         $(this).siblings().removeClass("expand-menu")
      } else{}
});
```

but my approach is wrong and it isn't working

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/BbF9K/

Thanks for the help

Comment: Here is a slimmed down version using your classes. http://jsfiddle.net/BbF9K/5/

Comment: This is what I am looking for but it only goes one level deep, is there a way to get this to work so that the model year is displayed? Right now the year won't show on click.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Simple fix: http://jsfiddle.net/BbF9K/7/

Comment: Is there any real difference between .children('ul.sub-menu') and .find('> ul.sub-menu')?

Comment: In this case, I don't think so. At least not from a logical standpoint. Technically their may be some differences. The ".children" method may be faster, depends on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm too tired to sort out all your classes, so I just used `hide()` and `show()`. Feel free to translate it back into CSS-driven statements.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BbF9K/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('li.menu-item-type-custom').on('click', function () {
        $(this).siblings().find('ul.sub-menu').hide();
        $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').show();
    });
});
```

Here's a version with slide effects:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BbF9K/3/

You could also tighten up your jQuery like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BbF9K/4/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('li.menu-item-type-custom').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().find('ul.sub-menu').slideUp();
        $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: I replaced .hide() with .removeClass("expand-menu") and .show() with .addClass("expand-menu") and got it to work! http://jsfiddle.net/BbF9K/6/